# Sending Json data from PHP to jQuery script to build table of posts Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

This is my ajax portion of code

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'get-planned-posts',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    $('div#alert').html(data)
                    $('div#alert').animate({top: '100'}, 'fast');
                    $('div#alert').fadeIn('slow');
                    $('div#alert').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow');
                },
```

And serverside PHP's (Codeigniter)

```
$query = $this->Devloger_admin->get_planned_posts();
        $this->is_ajax();
        $this->output->set_header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
        echo json_encode($query[1]['tytul']);
```

Query creates this result-array:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "62"
    ["tytul"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["data_dodania"]=>
    string(10) "0000-00-00"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "64"
    ["tytul"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["data_dodania"]=>
    string(10) "0000-00-00"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "65"
    ["tytul"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["data_dodania"]=>
    string(10) "0000-00-00"
  }
}
```

The problem is when I do

```
echo json_encode($query[1]['tytul']);
```

It properly sends title, and in showing box we got "3" according to the result array and this is correct.

But when I do like:

```
echo json_encode($query[1]);
```

It shows nothing, blank.

Next

```
echo json_encode($query);
```

Again blank. But that's whole array. I want to send whole array, with all posts and then create table from it. But something is wrong here, and I can't figure out what.

Below what json_encode creates from this result_array

```
[{"id":"62","tytul":"1","data_dodania":"0000-00-00"},{"id":"64","tytul":"3","data_dodania":"0000-00-00"},{"id":"65","tytul":"4","data_dodania":"0000-00-00"}]
```

Comment: Very confusing when you say `echo json_encode($query);` sends nothing but then you show properly json encoded string after. Not entirely clear what is or isn't working here. Note that if that json is sent .. `data` in `success` is an array that you need to loop ove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `data` variable in your success callback is a javascript object. you'll need to loop through it or stringify the array:

```
success: function(data) {
    $('div#alert').html(JSON.stringify(data));
},
```

something like this is probably what you want:

```
success: function(data) {
    var html = [];
    $.each(data, function(index, dataRow){
        html.push('<li>' + dataRow.id + ': ' + dataRow.tytul + '</li>');
    });
    $('div#alert').html(html.join(''));
},
```